# Spring kafka - Offset not setting on error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

In my listener after consuming the message if any exception happens then I throw an exception. If its successful then I acknowledge. But even if an exception thrown the offset is not getting set back. i.e the retry didn't happened as expected. The error event not coming again.

Also I see I am not consuming all the expected messages. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String,Result<FormatException,String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Result<FormatException, String>> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(this.consumerFactory());
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(3));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);

    return factory;
}


public ConsumerFactory<String, Result<FormatException, String>> consumerFactory() {
   kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
}
```

Listener Class

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${gpc.consumer.topic}")
    public void listenWithHeadersGPC(ConsumerRecord<String, Result<FormatException, String>> consumerRecord,
            Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        try {
            String body = consumerRecord.value().get();
            log.logInfo("Received message for " + GPCSourceName + ": " + body);
            log.logInfo("consumption successful from kafka. partition="+consumerRecord.partition()+", "
                    + "offset="+consumerRecord.offset());
                            if(body.contains("berlin+braze@gmail.com")) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("custom exception");
                            }
                            log.logInfo("Filtered message for " + GPCSourceName + " : " + body);
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            log.logError("Exception occurred in listenWithHeadersGPC: ", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I am doing `acknowledgment.acknowledge();` in my listener if there is no exceptions

Edit: Spring Kafka Version: 2.2.8

Answer (score 0):

`factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(3));`

With that configuration you should see 3 retries with zero delay between them; finally the record will be logged. 
By default, the offset of the "recovered" record won't be committed.

When posting questions like this; indicate which version you are using.

Starting with version 2.3, you can use `acknowledgment.nack(sleepTime)`; you can also call `setCommitRecovered(true)` on the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and the offset of the recovered record will be committed (with `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`).

This will all only happen if the exception is thrown to the container; if you catch the exception in your listener you won't see retries.

If you are not seeing retries at all, and your listener is throwing an exception, there is something wrong with your listener or configuration. Show all your configuration and the `@KafkaListener` code.

Comment: Thanks for responding. After throwing the exception, retry is working fine but its going in infinite loop

Comment: With `new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(3)` it should give up after 3 delivery attempts; something else is going on. Again; edit the question to show all the relevant code.